# Getting file contents in php

Tags: php, file, file-get-contents

I want to get contents of file that I browsed through a page. so I wrote  a php script for browsing it.
code is  given below

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my-file" size="50" maxlength="25"> <br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
```

and its php code is

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['my-file']['error']==0) { 
echo "The file name was: " . $_FILES['my-file']['name'] . "<br>";
echo "The file type is: " . $_FILES['my-file']['type'] . "<br>";
$file=$_FILES['my-file'];
$out = file_get_contents($file);
```

Then I want to print the content of this file ,
also I want to print "any sentence that have the word computer "

But it will not printing the content of file that I browsed , But it will printing the file name and file type details.

Is there is any way to print the values of file using file_get_contents()

get the result of a file in .txt file and it is downloadable format

Comment: you want `$_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']` not `$_FILES['my-file']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['my-file']['error']==0) { 
    echo "The file name was: " . $_FILES['my-file']['name'] . "<br>";
    echo "The file type is: " . $_FILES['my-file']['type'] . "<br>";
    $file=$_FILES['my-file'];
    $out = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
    print_r($out);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to store its result in a text file as downloadable format

Comment: using file_put_contents() you can store the data into text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['my-file']['error']==0) { 
echo "The file name was: " . $_FILES['my-file']['name'] . "<br>";
echo "The file type is: " . $_FILES['my-file']['type'] . "<br>";
$file=$_FILES['my-file'][''];//use ['tmp_name']
$out = file_get_contents($file);
```